# Consume kafka topic from Apache Beam

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-beam, apache-beam-io, apache-beam-kafkaio

I'm trying to catch the JSON events via Apache Beam and do the transformation and loading.

Since I'm in the development and R&D phases, I created a local Kafka server and created Python code to work as a producer and generate sample JSON messages.

The issue is as below:

The code im trying

```
def run(beam_args: Optional[List[str]] = None) -> None:
    TOPIC = "topic"
    OUTPUT_FILE = "output.json"
    beam_options = PipelineOptions(beam_args, save_main_session=True)
    beam_options.view_as(StandardOptions).streaming = True
    with beam.Pipeline(options=beam_options) as pipeline:
        msg_kv_bytes = (pipeline | 'ReadData' >> ReadFromKafka(consumer_config=CONSUMER_CONFIG,
                                                               topics=[TOPIC],
                                                               ))

        def process_and_write_to_file(message):
            key, value = message
            json_data = json.loads(value)
            with open(OUTPUT_FILE, 'a') as output_file:
                output_file.write(json.dumps(json_data) + '\n')

        _ = msg_kv_bytes | 'ProcessAndWriteToFile' >> beam.Map(process_and_write_to_file)
```

Expected: write messages in a file when it receive new messages

Results: The code is running without any errors or exceptions, and there is no console or output.json file created

Actions:

I have changed ReadFromKafka constructor with max_num_records=1 as below

```
msg_kv_bytes = (pipeline | 'ReadData' >> ReadFromKafka(consumer_config=CONSUMER_CONFIG,
                                                       topics=[TOPIC],
                                                       max_num_records=1
                                                       ))
```

Results: Once the producer generates a message, this will create an output.json file, and then execution will stop.

So my concern is why the code not work according to expected behavior.

Comment: First, just try to do `beam.Map(print)` to make sure everything works with Kafka. If so, `process_and_write_to_file` has some issues. One thing I noticed is "output.json" is used for all messages. I doubt it is thread-safe. I suggest you use `WriteToFiles`. One example is https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataflow-cookbook/blob/main/Python/file/write_files.py